# Should I let my incoming applied school know that I've optained a scholarship from another school?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, funding

This is in an Australian PhD application context, and I'll try to provide as much info as possible without revealing anyone's identity.

I have obtained a full PhD scholarship from a less prestigious school last November. However, due to job arrangements, I had to defer the commencement of my PhD program to the upcoming November. During my current job tenure, my direct superior recommended me to a better ranked school (also in Australia). So I am in touch with the new school now (and the new supervisor knows that I've got a scholarship from the earlier application).

The new supervisor suggested me to note in my new application that I've obtained a full scholarship from the old school, saying there might be better chances of me getting a scholarship in this new school if they know that I've had a scholarship from another school (not sure what's the logic here).

This brings me to the following questions:

1. **Should I, as the new supervisor suggested, mention in my new application that I've got a scholarship somewhere else?** From my point of view, it sounds like I'm pressuring the new school to give me a scholarship, and they'll consider this disrespectful.
2. **Would you consider this a moral delimma** - given that I have accepted and deferred the offer & scholarship from the 1st school, and now I'm shopping around the market?
3. **I heard from fellow PhD candidates that when it comes to PhD, school ranking isn't as important. Is it correct?** I guess my current dilemma is in big part caused by school ranking - in my workplace, everyone comes from prestigious schools. So I just can't get past the fact that if I don't try the new school, I will end up in a less reputable school (even though my supervisor will be a super great gentleman - as in both personality and academic achievement).

Comment: please limit the post to one question at a time, otherwise the question will be closed due to being to broad.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/110902/is-it-okay-to-explore-other-grad-school-options-while-deferring-admission-for-ot