# Changing university and advisor midway through PhD

Tags: phd, graduate-school, advisor

I have read several posts regarding this question such as "[Is transferring to another university an option for an unhappy PhD student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/is-transferring-to-another-university-an-option-for-an-unhappy-phd-student)" and
"[Changing University in First year of Phd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44780/changing-university-in-first-year-of-phd)", but none of them apply to my situation.

Background: I am a first-year computer science Ph.D. student, I started my Ph.D. in the spring semester and so I am in the second semester. I am fully funded, but the problem is that the income I get from the university is very low and I did not know that I have to pay about 2000 each semester for insurance. My mind is always busy thinking about how can I provide this money. It's hard, as I have the potential to do really well but most of the time I am struggling with financial issues.

The second but minor issue is my advisor, she isn't an expert in her field, we just go forward with trial and error, and I am the kind of person who needs to read deeply to understand all aspects before trying. We have to have a strong reason to test an approach so before testing we should take a good amount of time, but she just likes to force me to test without in-depth understanding. It's disappointing for me. Most of the time the results are not good. I said this is a minor issue as I am self-learner and I will find a way to do the way I like.

I talked with my advisor regarding this, she said we have to survive in this time, and I don't have any other sources, she tried to make me happy by not giving me the TA of a subject that I don't like, but it does not work for me. I need to make my mind free and focus on the research.

With these explanations, how can I convince another university and professor to accept me?

Comment: Given the possible conflict with your advisor, may I first suggest you to change your SE profile, name and picture, to avoid being recognized?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano thanks yea I have to do it, but I have heard that saying conflictit with the professor has the negative context and should not do it, they may think I am not some one put up with the situations, or someone that complain all the time, but really I am not. I am very patient but found myself really broken and helpless, though even my professor likes the way I am thinking and most of the time I have something to offer in terms of idea

Comment: I think the advisor part is less of a concern, assuming she is an experienced  researcher with quality publications.  For example, my students quickly become more of an expert in a topic than me after 6-12 months.  Trial-n-error is fine but you can minimize going down a rabbit hole by first getting a better understanding of the method/problem yourself.   Then provide evidences to your supervisor why it is good/bad.  As for the financial issue, there is no easy fix.   Best of luck.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus many thanks for your advice, yea I agree with you that supervisor part is really not important and I mentioned that. I just said that to give you a big picture of the situation.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus also somehow she isn't very experienced in publications, though she has been a professor for many years. but its not like a concern as far as im self-learner, do you think I can explain about the financial difficulties here to professors and convince them>? or its unreasonable